# How to get kafka offset with Kafka SSL&ACL

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka cluster with SSL&ACL
when i trun off ACL,i can get offset form kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh

```html
[root@node128 kafka_2.10-0.10.0.0]# bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka-test --group consumer-group-1 --topic testtopic
[2016-09-02 14:03:51,722] WARN WARNING: ConsumerOffsetChecker is deprecated and will be dropped in releases following 0.9.0. Use ConsumerGroupCommand instead. (kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker$)
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
consumer-group-1 testtopic                      0   99981           99981           0               none
```

but when i configure like this

```html
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/ssl_key/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=xdata123
ssl.key.password=xdata123
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/ssl_key/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=xdata123

ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS

security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
```

just trun on  ACL and use kafka-acls.sh to add principal for topic testtopic and group consumer-group-1，

I cannot get result of kafka offset from kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh.
Is there something deferent in ACL?
How can I get topics` offset in kafka ACL model?

Answer (score 0):

Per this site: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authorization.html

You need an acl with the following config:

Read on Group. Also make sure that you set the pattern correctly